# Date Format dd/mm/yyyy to yyyy/mm/dd

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime, sql-server-2012

How can I convert `dd/mm/yyyy` to `yyyy/mm/dd`. Sometimes SQL Server changes month with day.

For example: `02/12/2014(dd/mm/yyyy)` to `2014/02/12(yyyy/dd/mm)` but correct is `2014/12/02(yyyy/mm/dd)`.

Comment: Prefer, where possible, to just use correct datetime types (e.g. `date`, `time`, `datetime2` in SQL Server, whatever the types are in you application languages). These don't *have* formats. Ideally, you parse from strings as close to user input as possible, and convert back into strings as late in UI presentation as possible. Every else, *avoid* strings and let language bindings deal with translating between types.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to specify the format of the date you need to convert it (slightly annoying)

For the yyyy/mm/dd format use

```
convert(varchar, getdate(), 111)
```

you can see a good list of the different format types here
https://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below -

`SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),<yourdate>,103)`  -- for `dd/mm/yyyy`

`SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),<yourdate>,111)`  -- for `yyyy/mm/dd`

Answer (score -1):

I'd go for this:

If you're storing your date as a string (which is **not recommended**)

```
DECLARE @Date VARCHAR(10) = '02/12/2014';

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(DATE, @Date, 103), 111);
```

1. Ensure that your date can be converted to `DATE`
2. Convert it to desired [date style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

If you're storing your date as a [date](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx)

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @Date, 111);
```

Outputs:

`2014/12/02`